# Parsing CSV when a cell has a trailing newline character

Tags: php, csv, parsing

I've been tasked with importing a huge list of products stored in a CSV using PHP.

What I'm trying to do is this...

```
$aRows = array_map('str_getcsv', file($sFilePath));
```

I've enclosed all fields in double quotes. When I run the import I get some weird results and I *think* it's because some cells (the product description) have a trailing newline character.

The problem is that I can't figure out how to strip this as the CSV rows are also delimited by the same character

I tried using regex to look for any newline that *Wasn't* preceded by a double quote and is succeeded by one but I don't know if I got the regex correct

```
$csvData = preg_replace("/(^\")\n(\")/i", "$1$3", $csvData);
```

Any help on this would be amazing as I've hit a complete brick wall

Comment: _“some cells (the product description) have a trailing newline character”_ - can you show what that actually looks like inside the csv file? Because in combination with _“as the CSV rows are also delimited by the same character”_ it sounds like you might rather be dealing with messed up data here to begin with, and should rather ask the provider of the csv to fix it …?

Comment: I totally agree; It's a freelance project. I asked the agency to push back on the client but they're unwilling. It's provided as an XSLX. When I open it in LibreOffice and click into the description fields there's a return at the end of the description. Not sure how to show you the data

Comment: I guess your use of `file` might be messing things up here. file does not care about any field delimiters or escape characters that might be in place in the data to _properly_ transport a line break as field content - it is simply going to hack your input into pieces at _every_ line break character it finds. Try using `fgetcsv` instead, that has the means to handle this properly build in.

Comment: I tried file_get_contents when trying to regex out the newline. Would I still have the same issues there do you think?

Comment: Without seeing any sample data, hard to tell. I would really give `fgetcsv` a go here, it is the established and proven tool to handle CSV input in PHP.

Comment: Just in case have you checked the encoding of the CSV file?

Comment: Well I'll be damned `fgetcsv` actually solved this! @CBroe if you want to add an answer I'll happily accept it

Comment: Cheers, glad it helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $aRows = array_map('str_getcsv', file($sFilePath));

I guess your use of `file` might be messing things up here. `file` does not care about any field delimiters or escape characters that might be in place in the data to properly transport a line break as field content - it is simply going to hack your input into pieces at *every* line break character it finds.

Try using `fgetcsv` instead, that has the means to handle this properly build in.

It is capable of recognizing that a newline occurred within a column value between enclosure characters, and therefor does not takes this as “line ends here” as `file` would, but knows that it has to read on to get the full CSV data *row* here.